# Grails file upload not using correct content-type

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, gsp

I created a file upload in Grails, but I can't find a way to get the request to use `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`. The requests are being sent with
`Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This is my form

```
        <g:uploadForm controller='asset' action='upload'>
            <label>Select file(s) to upload</label>
            <input type='file' id='fileUpload' name='filesToUpload' multiple />
            <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload"/>
        </g:uploadForm>
```

In Config.groovy, `grails.mime.types` contains `multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'` and `grails.web.disable.multipart=false`. I am using Spring Security, and the `AssetsController` is `@Secured`.

How do I get the requests to be sent with `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 1):

if the `<g:uploadForm >`-Tag does not what's described in the manual:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/ref/Tags/uploadForm.html

> Identical to the standard form tag except that it sets the enctype attribute to "multipart/form-data" automatically.

then you could try to use the normal `<g:form >`-Tag and add the enctype attribute or even don't use the tag at all. A simple HTML-Upload will work, too:

```
<form action="${g:createLink controller:'', action:''}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileupload">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```